# What is the difference between enabled : false and index : 'no' in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

When mapping fields in elaticsearch, what's the difference between setting

```
enabled : false
```

for the field vs setting

```
index : 'no'
```

?

Comment: relevant conversation: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/What-s-the-difference-between-quot-enabled-quot-quot-index-quot-and-quot-store-quot-td4029715.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As I understand, `index: no` is applicable to core types only, whereas `enabled: false` is defined for `object` types and ElasticSearch
specific fields such as `_index`, `_all`, ...

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html#enabled):

> The `enabled` setting, which can be applied **only to** the **mapping type** and to **object fields**. It causes Elasticsearch to skip parsing of the contents of the field entirely.

---

Example of `enabled` usage (YAML format):

```yaml
    ---
    ...
    _all:
          enabled: false
    ...
```